# ubuntu PDF::Template installation

Tags: pdf, ubuntu-14.04, perl-module, cpan

trying to install CPAN PDF::Template module, I got this error message :

```
  RKINYON/PDF-Template-0.22.tar.gz
  Tests succeeded but one dependency not OK (pdflib_pl)
    RKINYON/PDF-Template-0.22.tar.gz
    [dependencies] -- NA
  Running make install
    make test had returned bad status, won't install without force
  Failed during this command:
   RKINYON/PDF-Template-0.22.tar.gz             : make_test NO one dependency not OK (pdflib_pl)
```

Any idea why ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As [module docs say](https://metacpan.org/pod/PDF::Template#LIMITATIONS) you need PDFlib lite.
You can get it from [PDFlib website](http://www.pdflib.com)